# Can two dependencies in Gradle be assigned different transitive dependency versions?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, transitive-dependency

We have a Gradle Java project, and our build.gradle has various module dependencies.  Suppose two of those module dependencies are dependencyA and dependencyB:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'org.example.dependency:dependencyA:0.13.0'
   implementation 'com.example.dependency:dependencyB:1.0.0'
}
```

dependencyA is an older implementation and has a transitive dependency to org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6

dependencyB is a newer implementation and has a transitive dependency to
org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0

Is there a way within our build.gradle to have dependencyA refer to the older transitive dependency org.apache.avro:avro:1.7.6, and have dependencyB and others refer to the newer transitive dependency org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0?

I tried using strict but that seems to force all the dependencies to use that transitive version.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the exact same issue right now.